# How to put activityindicator middle of a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, center, uiactivityindicatorview

I have put activity indicator

```
 spinner.center = CGPointMake( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2);
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
```

But this is not properly centered in the table view. Because table view can scroll.
How can i put a spinner in the center of the screen.

Comment: You are making it centered of screen not of `tableView`. It will contain the **height** of `navigaitonBar` and `statusBar` too. **table view can scroll** doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: For Swift 3 you can use the following:
Please check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/41748916/2307418

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try with bellow code:-

```
    spinner.center = CGPointMake( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2);
    yourAppdelegateClass *appDelegate = (yourAppdelegateClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.window addSubview:spinner];
```

**Code Output is:-**

[image]

Comment: UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2);
    ;
        
    UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [mainWindow addSubview: spinner];                                                    This works for me.

Comment: bravo.. this is same thing you UIWindow mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]; and object of appdelegate and you get window as par my code... :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
spinner.center = tableview.center;
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: It'd be much safer to use `CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds))` since `tableview`'s center is going to be relative to it's superview and not itself!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add your indicater(Spinner) on table view instead of sel.view.
and define the area frame on the indicater.

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution, because I have to put a spinner at detail view controller. Maybe it will help somebody.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.spinner];
}
```

And for positioning:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{  
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.navigationController.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.navigationController.view layoutIfNeeded];
    self.spinner.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2, 10, 10);
}
```

Spinner will be always at center of your table view at detail view controller.

Answer (score -1):

Please find below code:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView* spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.center = CGPointMake( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2);
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[spinner startAnimating];
[appDelegate.window addSubview:spinner];
```