# Place activity indicator over uitable view

Tags: swift

I've placed an Activity indicator in a `UITableView` within the storyboard.
How can I center it in the middle of the screen and in front of the table view?

I've tried:

```
self.activityIndicator.center = self.tableView.center
```

But now, the activity indicator is in the top-middle of the view!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's the steps: Followed Chrissukhram instructions.

1. drag a view on top of table view Step
2. drag activity
       indicator on to the view
3. Align the activity indicator to
       horizontal and vertical centre in container
4. make IBOutlet
       connection for both view and activity indicator
5. start the
       activity indicator
6. stop and hide : `activityIndicatorLarge.hidesWhenStopped = true
               activityView.hidden = true`

Answer (score 39):

To display an activity indicator while data is loading in a `UITableView`, you can create a UIView and add it to the main view (in the center of the `UITableView`). If you want to display it as shown bellow:

[image]

You can do that with the fnuctions `setLoadingScreen` and `removeLoadingScreen` (if you want to see a sample project you can go [here](https://github.com/angeldev/iOSDev/tree/master/activityIndicatorOverUITableView)):

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    /// Data source of the tableView
    var rows: [String] = []

    /// View which contains the loading text and the spinner
    let loadingView = UIView()

    /// Spinner shown during load the TableView
    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    /// Text shown during load the TableView
    let loadingLabel = UILabel()


    // MARK: Methods

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        setLoadingScreen()

        loadData()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return rows.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)!
        cell.textLabel!.text = rows[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }


    // MARK: Private methods

    // Load data in the tableView
    private func loadData() {

        // Simulate a delay of some operations as a HTTP Request            
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(20)) {

            self.rows = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3", "Row 4", "Row 5"]

            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
            self.removeLoadingScreen()

        }

    }

    // Set the activity indicator into the main view
    private func setLoadingScreen() {

        // Sets the view which contains the loading text and the spinner
        let width: CGFloat = 120
        let height: CGFloat = 30
        let x = (tableView.frame.width / 2) - (width / 2)
        let y = (tableView.frame.height / 2) - (height / 2) - (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!
        loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)

        // Sets loading text
        loadingLabel.textColor = .gray
        loadingLabel.textAlignment = .center
        loadingLabel.text = "Loading..."
        loadingLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 140, height: 30)

        // Sets spinner
        spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
        spinner.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        spinner.startAnimating()

        // Adds text and spinner to the view
        loadingView.addSubview(spinner)
        loadingView.addSubview(loadingLabel)

        tableView.addSubview(loadingView)

    }

    // Remove the activity indicator from the main view
    private func removeLoadingScreen() {

        // Hides and stops the text and the spinner
        spinner.stopAnimating()
        spinner.isHidden = true
        loadingLabel.isHidden = true

    }

}
```

Comment: +1, but in my case removeLoadingScreen() did't behave properly, label and indicator were still visible even after table cells appeared. After couple of seconds label and indicator disappeared. I fixed it with         self.loadingView.removeFromSuperview() in removeLoadingScreen()

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way is to add a UIActivityIndicatorView in your tableView backgroundView

```
    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)

    spinner.startAnimating()
    tableView.backgroundView = spinner
```

it will be centered by default.

Comment: Have you tested this in a TableViewController? This doesn't work for me.

Comment: use let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)

Answer (score 5):

If you use complex view:

```
 func setupSpinner(){
    spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height:40))
    spinner.color = UIColor(Colors.Accent)
    self.spinner.center = CGPoint(x:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2, y:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 2)
    self.view.addSubview(spinner)
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If this activity indicator is for loading information into the  `UITableView` you should create a separate loading `UIView` that is the same size as the `UITableView` and place the Activity Indicator in the center of that view, not the `UITableView` itself.

Then add the loading `UIView` to your main view (above the table view) and set it to hidden or visible depending on the status of the loading.

Comment: how can i place a uiView over a tableView?

Comment: You can add your loading UIView to the ViewControllers main view (self.view) after you add your UITableView. Essentially, the order you add views to each other is the order they will be stacked when displayed.

Comment: So i have to change the storyboard in that way:

Comment: Yes if you are doing this in storyboard it is much easier, just add the UIView "below" the tableView in the Document Outline view (the left of the storyboard)

Comment: @chrissukhram, does that still work in Xcode 8? When I try to drag a uiview under the tableView in the doc outline Xcode keeps pushing it between `First Responder` and `Exit` rather than inside the controller?

Comment: @JamesLingo yeah it is just simply adding a UIView to the ViewController so it should work. If the view is going between First Responder and Exit try to move your mouse to the left a little bit in doc outline and go up, eventually you will get the blue line to show up right after the UITableView.

Comment: Weird no matter what I try it won't except it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you used directly UITableView in your storyboard. This is why you can't drag uiview top of the main view(tableview). Delete UItableview controller and drag a UIViewController into the storyboard, instead. Then drag a tableview into it. then drag another view over tableview for activity indicator. don't forget to handle UItableviewdelegate and datasourse methods in your UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

In the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your tableViewController try this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: screenSize.width / 2, y: screenSize.height / 2, width: 5, height: 5)
    activityIndicator.color = .white
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

    if let baseView = view.superview {
        baseView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    }
}
```

`activityIndicator` is a stored property of my `TableViewController` class.